# Random number consecutive c#

Tags: c#, random

Hello Im trying to generate  many consecutive random number with a for but i always get the same number. The problem is that I need the for.   This is my methode.

```
public static int roll(int numberRoll, int maxNumber)
    {
        Random random1 = new Random();
        int someRoll = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < numberRoll; ++i )
        {
            someRoll += random1.Next(1,maxNumber);
        }
        return someRoll;
```

Comment: How i can put it outside of the methode beacause it become an object ?

Comment: @Thombien you do it by passing in a `Random` in to the function in the place that calls this function it likely too has a loop, you need to create the new Random outside of that loop. This is safer than using a static Random because Random is not thread safe.

Comment: ok thx I was missing the static before